# Serialisation of Extrinsic objects

Tags: transactions, extrinsic, signing, parse

Generating transaction via `ApiPromise` through `api.tx.xxx` method generated a `SubmittableExtrinsicFunction` object. Which has a `toJSON()` function that return what I would call a raw transaction.

Is there any way I can recreate a `SubmittableExtrinsicFunction` from the raw transaction?

Also if you sign the `SubmittableExtrinsicFunction` you get a `Submittable` object. Which again has a `toJSON()` function the question again is how to go from json result back to `Submittable` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do the serialization here is to use `toHex()` instead of `toJSON()`.

Take a look at the example of how to do it:

```
const transfer = await api.tx.balances.transfer(BOB, 100000000000);
// Serialize
const serializedTransaction = transfer.toHex();
// Deserialize
const deserializedTransaction = api.tx(serializedTransaction);
```

Now you have the SubmittableExtrinsic again and you can send it:

```
const result = await deserializedTransaction.signAndSend(alice);
```