# Decoupled composition, signing, and publishing with @polkadot/api

Tags: polkadot-js

I'm building an application whose architecture decouples transaction composition, signing, and publishing. These processes literally live in separate components that communicate with each other, but do not belong on the same application.

This means that after composing a transaction with:

```
const tx = api.tx.pallet.dispatchable(...args);
```

I don't want to use `signAndSend`, but instead sign the raw encoded call, and once I have the signature, I need to publish it to a substrate node. The info I have at this point is `encodedCall` and `signature`.

How can I publish a transaction with that information alone? Is there a way to reconstruct the `SubmittableExtrinsic` object to use `.send()`? Or is there a way to make a raw RPC call that achieves the same result?

*Update*:
My question is: what would the third parameter of `sign()` be?

Comment: Check out this answer https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7198/380

Comment: That's great info! However, it's not the complete solution. I can recover the `SubmittableExtrinsic` with `api.tx(encodedTx)`, but the signature is also obtained in a decoupled manner. So I would need to do something like this: `tx.addSignature(sender, sig, ???)`.

I don't really know what the third param of `addSignature` is supposed to be, though...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you don't want to use `signAndSend`, just use `sign`. This gives you a signed transaction that you can broadcast at a later date. You don't need anything else.

Comment: My question is: what would the third parameter of `sign` be?

Comment: Your payload. This answer may help: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7747/380

Comment: Cool, I think that's what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @forgetso please write that comment in an answer

Comment: @Simson Shouldn't it be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: well maybe ... I personally prefer answers on duplicated questions too and it will take forever to get five votes on this stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of `sign` is the `payload`, which can be constructed by following the instructions in [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/7747/380).